# Compare statement not working with User Input in assembly language x86 nasm linux

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cmp

I am trying to create calculator in x86 assembly language, I am taking input to check which operation user wants, but cmp statement is not working. After taking input program directly jumps on add_nums. The second thing I want to ask is that how useful it will be to learn assembly language in-depth in today's era

```
STDOUT equ 1;
    STDIN equ 0;
    SYS_EXIT equ 1;
    SYS_WRITE equ 4;
    SYS_READ equ 3;
    
    section .bss
        choice resd 1;
        opOne resb 4;
        opTwo resb 4;
        result resb 4;
    
    section .data
        msgBanner db "Enter 1 for addtion : ", 0xA, 0xD;
        lenBanner equ $ - msgBanner;
        msgInpOne db "Enter First Operand : ", 0xA, 0xD;
        lenOne equ $ - msgInpOne;
        msgInpTwo db "Enter Second Operand : ", 0xA, 0xD;
        lenTwo equ $- msgInpTwo;
        endMsg db "Sum is : ";
        lenEndMsg equ $ - endMsg;
        test1 dd 1;
        test2 dd 2;
    
    
    section .text
        global _start;
    
    _start:
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE;
        mov ebx, STDOUT;
        mov ecx, msgBanner;
        mov edx, lenBanner;
        int 0x80;
        mov eax, SYS_READ;
        mov ebx, STDIN;
        mov ecx, choice;
        mov edx, 4;
        int 0x80;
        mov ecx, [test1];
        cmp ecx, [choice];
        je sub_nums;    
        mov ecx, [test2];
        cmp ecx, [choice];
        je add_nums;
    add_nums:
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE;
        mov ebx, STDOUT;
        mov ecx, msgInpOne;
        mov edx, lenOne;
        int 0x80;   
        mov eax, SYS_READ;
        mov ebx, STDIN;
        mov ecx, opOne;
        mov edx, 4;
        int 0x80;
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE;
        mov ebx, STDOUT;
        mov ecx, msgInpTwo;
        mov edx, lenTwo;
        int 0x80;
        mov eax, SYS_READ;
        mov ebx, STDIN;
        mov ecx, opTwo;
        mov edx, 4;
        int 0x80;
        mov eax, [opOne];
        mov ebx, [opTwo];
        sub eax, '0';
        sub ebx, '0';
        add eax, ebx;
        add eax, '0';   
        mov [result], eax;
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE;
        mov ebx, STDOUT;
        mov ecx, endMsg;
        mov edx, lenEndMsg;
        int 0x80;   
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE;
        mov ebx, STDOUT;
        mov ecx, result;
        mov edx, 4;
        int 0x80;   
        mov eax, SYS_EXIT;
        int 0x80;
    sub_nums:
        mov [result], eax;
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE;
        mov ebx, STDOUT;
        mov ecx, endMsg;
        mov edx, lenEndMsg;
        int 0x80;
        mov eax, SYS_EXIT;
        int 0x80;
```

Comment: You are comparing 4 bytes. You are comparing binary not text. Your `add_nums` is directly after `je add_nums` so execution will fall through into it anyway. PS: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: how can I compare text and where should be add_nums;

Comment: Use `test1 db "1"` or even just `cmp byte [choice], "1"` (mind the quotes). You need some code between `je add_nums` and `add_nums` to handle if the input is not 1 or 2 otherwise you will fall through into `add_nums` anyway.

Comment: Thankyou so much dude you saved my day.  In my question's body I have another question can you answer that too, its theoretical.